# Need help in refactoring Retry logic pattern

Tags: c#, generics

I want to send some commands to the serial port and listen for a response.
The response from the port could be well formed data or corrupt data. In that case I have to retry sending the same command after a strategic timeout

At the moment I'm using a while loop to achieve this. However I'm looking for a more simple and reusable approach for all the ~30 commands that I need to send.

```
int retryCount = 3;

while(retryCount > 0){
 _SerialPort.WriteLine("$0\r");
 Thread.Sleep(300);

 //Check response 
 RESPONSE_STATE iResponse = ProcessResponse();
 if (iResponse == RESPONSE_STATE.NOERROR)
  {
     //process response
     break;
  }
  else
  {
     retryCount--;
     //repeat operation
  }
}
```

I want to implement a Generic method something similar to below, Which I can call once and it shall take care of retrying logic implementation. Instead of the exception handling I want to query for the response from the serial port.

```
public T Do<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount = 3)
            {
                var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
                for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (retry > 0)
                            Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
                        return action();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       exceptions.Add(ex);
                    }
                }
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            }
```

Ex :  `int returnCount = Do(MyMethod,TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(300),3);`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: and what is a problem? Your solution should work

Comment: How do I modify this retry logic to call the methods based on ProcessResponse() instead of calling whenever there is an exception

Comment: Check out polly: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly